# Prevent android edit bar using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, phonegap

I am developing an e-book app on Cordova/PhoneGap in which I want to be able to select text from some sections but not from others. Cordova has this CSS out of the box to avoid selecting:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;    /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
-webkit-user-select: none;      /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
```

And I allow selection by redefining the value of `user-select` to `text`, like for example in the `#content` section:

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  user-select: text !important;
  -webkit-user-select: text !important;
}
```

This works fine, and I can select text, but it has a problem: the default edit bar (in light blue in the screenshot below) from android shows up, and I want to avoid that as I'll have my own controllers for copy/sharing. What can I do to avoid it from showing up?

[image: android edit bar displayed on screenshot]

I would prefer a Cordova/PhoneGap solution, but if the only way is using Java and modifying the java code generated by Cordova, I'll be open to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a DIV-element that should not trigger the default-edit-bar.

These are the steps I've taken:

1. Remove `user-select` and `-webkit-user-select` from the css-class `#content` because this always allows to open the default-edit-bar.
2. Add the [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable)-Attribute to `#content`, so that individual words can be selected as well. And although `#content` has also got `user-select: none` a `selectstart`-event is fired when an user wants to select this element. This can be utilized within a `selectstart`-handler to open your own popup/window and not the default-edit-bar.

Note that: The following example shows of how you can select a certain element within `#content`. So in this example the user is (also) able to select certain words within a paragraph not only the whole paragraph, but you have to wrap them by using a `SPAN`-element for instance to highlight only them.

This should work with all platforms:

```
<style>

  div {
    touch-callout: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 50px;
  }

  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }

</style>
<body>

<div>
  This text can not be selected at all
</div>

<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
  This text can be <span>selected</span> but not by using default editor
  This text can be <span>selected</span> but not by using default editor
  This text can be <span>selected</span> but not by using default editor
</div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var selected = false;
var isHolding = false;
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('selectstart', function(event) {
  // preventDefault prevents to open the default-editor
  event.preventDefault();

  // prevents to fire selectstart-event several times
  if(selected)return;
  selected = true;

  // simulate delay like a real selection event by using setTimeout
  setTimeout(function(){

    // is user still holding onto screen, then select text
    // otherwise nothing is highlighted
    if(isHolding) {
      // event.target contains the element that is selected
      // it can be a SPAN- or the whole #content-element
      var selectedElement = event.target.parentNode;
      console.log(selectedElement);
      highlightTextNode(selectedElement);

      var selectedText = selectedElement.textContent ? selectedElement.textContent : selectedElement.innerText;
      alert("this text is selected: "+ selectedText);

      //  HERE! You might want to open a popup here to show/process this selected text

    }

    // reset selected
    selected = false;

  },1000);

},false);


// check for a user really touched #content to know whether a text should be highlighted or not
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('touchstart',function(event) {
  isHolding = true;
},false);


// check for a user really left #content to know whether a text should be highlighted or not
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('touchend',function(event) {
  isHolding = false;
},false);


// just a function to highlight any HTML-Node
function highlightTextNode(node){
  if(node)node.setAttribute('style','color: yellow');
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This didn't work with my code (although it worked by itself), I need to try to adapt it as it is still not exactly what I'm looking for (with this solution whole blocks will be selected instead of specific text)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear, but as I stated in my answer certain HTML-entities (like SPAN) have to be used, so that word-selection is possible. Nevertheless in my answer you can mark "selected"-words individually, because they are wrapped by SPAN's